# Hyperlink replace the link text when no record value

Tags: asp.net

I am using VB.NET. Basically, I am trying to hide the link if there is no FilePath record from the database, but I couldn't figure it out.

This is my code in the EditItemTemplate in the DetailsView:

```
<EditItemTemplate >
    <div style="display:inline; width:40%; ">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkFileUploaded" runat=server NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>' Visible="False" >Attached File</asp:HyperLink> 
    </div>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

What I want to do is if Eval("FilePath") = "", then display the text "No Attached File".

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hyperlink, so it is best to hide it - by dynamically setting the visible property based on whether the FilePath is null or not:

```
Visible='<%# If(Eval("FilePath").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, False, True) %>'
```

For example:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkFileUploaded" runat=server NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>' Visible='<%# If(Eval("FilePath").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, False, True) %>' >Attached File</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then have a label that shows when FilePath is null:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text='No Attached File'
    Visible='<%# If(Eval("FilePath").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, True, False) %>'></asp:Label>
```

They would both go inside your EditItemTemplate:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <div style="display:inline; width:40%; ">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="linkFileUploaded" runat=server NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("FilePath")%>' Visible='<%# If(Eval("FilePath").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, False, True) %>' >Attached File</asp:HyperLink>
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" Text='No Attached File'
    Visible='<%# If(Eval("FilePath").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, True, False) %>'></asp:Label>
    </div>
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement." for the "<%# !Eval("FilePath").Equals(DBNull.Value)%>"  is it because I am using VB.NET?

Comment: Yes, I have changed it to VB.Net syntax.

Comment: I replace "NOT with "!" and it works. Thank you very much for helping.